# Select Posts along with its comments with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have an entity framework query that brings all the posts along with the comments.
I am trying to convert EF code to a T-SQL stored procedure. This is the EF Code,

```
                (from post in context.Post
                orderby post.Id descending
                select new Post
                {
                    Id = post.Id,
                    PostText = post.PostText,
                    Comments = (from c in context.Comment
                                where c.PostId == post.Id 
                                orderby c.Id descending
                                select new CommentDto
                                {
                                    Id = c.Id,
                                    CommentText = c.CommentText
                                }

                                )
                }).AsNoTracking();
```

How do i convert the above code to T-SQL?
Do i need to to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with post and comment table  and then filter it out on the client side ?

Comment: EF is automatically binding values to models.  Do you want a single result set with duplicate Posts or two results; one with posts, and one with all related comments to Posts?

Comment: If i want to show the way i am showing now, each post and its corresponding comments , which one would be the easier way ?

Comment: I don't know, because you've only asked how to retrieve data, not any code on how you want to show it.